# Javascript: select the text in the currently focussed input field

Tags: javascript, input, focus

I would like to select the text of the input field which currently has focus, so when the user starts typing, the text which is currently in the input field is gone. Can I do this with javascript (or jquery)?

In case the field which currently has focus is not an input field, nothing has to happen.

thanks!

EDIT:
To all the answerers: you all misunderstood (so probably my question was not clear).
I don't want to select the text on the moment the input field gets the focus. I would like to have a javascript function which selects the text of the input field which has the focus at that moment.

Comment: Of all input fields or just certain one(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood what you were looking for I think that I have a better understanding of it now. Does this do more of what you were looking to acheive?

```
//If not using 1.7 for jquery you can use bind
$('input, textarea').on({
    focusin: function(){
        $(this).addClass("focused");
    },
    focusout: function(){
        $(this).removeClass("focused");
    }
});

function highlightText()
{
    var focused = $('input.focused,textarea.focused');

    if (focused.size()) {
        focused.get(0).select();   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GXFpR/1/

Comment: removing is not what I want... I just want to select the text of the input field

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z55UZ/

```
 $("input, textarea").focus(
     function()
     {
         this.select();
     }
  )
```

EDIT:

here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z55UZ/2/

In the example is selected the last focused element; but if you look at the code the var childInputHasFocus and whoHasFocus are never setted to false...when you want to stop the selecting feature?

Where you wanna call the function? Because the click event sets the active/focused element as is caller.

Comment: @david, I'm not sure what you mean by your `tail between my legs` comment. I simply edited Edward's and Jason's answers so that I could remove my down-votes. I mis-read the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with onfocus and then use `this.select()` as inline

```
  <input name="" type="text" value="test test" onfocus="this.select()" />
```

UPDATE: a more universal approach,  will add focus to inputs of the text type also input text's that are not readonly

```
  window.onload = setFocus();
```

or call beneth the last form input field

```
  setFocus();
```

main

```
setFocus = function(){
  var i = [];
  i = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var t=0; t < i.length; t++){
       if(i.item(t).type == "text" && i.item(t).readOnly == false){
          i.item(t).onfocus = function (){this.select()};
     }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="theTextBox" onfocus="selectText()" value="some value"></input>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectText() {
    document.getElementById("theTextBox").select();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```